# When I import text file into R, I get a special character appended to the first value of the first column

Tags: r

Sometimes when I import text file into R, i get the character "ï»¿" appended to the first value of the first column.  Does anyone know why this is?

For example a text file with the values:

```
2011_21,3130
2010_51,4153
2011_16,3168
2010_20,3945
2012_38,2099
2012_17,2436
2010_40,2090
2011_2 ,1462
```

bring up the following results in R:

1st I read the file in:

```
ts_data <- read.csv("yr_wk sales.csv", header=FALSE)
head(ts_data)
```

This is the data that's returned:

```
 V1   V2
1 ï»¿2011_21 3130
2    2010_51 4153
3    2011_16 3168
4    2010_20 3945
5    2012_38 2099
6    2012_17 2436
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: Which locale are you using?

Comment: R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R's read.csv prepending 1st column name with junk text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text)

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the following:

```
ts_data <- read.csv("yr_wk sales.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", header=FALSE)
head(ts_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem when I worked with the txt file on Microsoft Word. I copied the data from the txt saved by MS Word to a new txt file using Notepad and the problem was solved.

Comment: For whatever reason, Notepad didn't work. But, I dropped it into SublimeText and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As I've noted in the comments, this is the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). There is discussion here (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html) about dealing with it.

If you know the file encoding, you can sort it out. Assuming it is UTF-8:

```
ts_data <- read.table("yr_wk sales.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I keep finding this issue in .csv files created by windows users.  The weird thing is, there's often a Byte Order Mark at the start of the file, but not at the end.  So when I set the file encoding as UTF-8, I get the following `error: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'myfile'`

Comment: I have the same problem, and 'fileEncoding = "UTF-8" does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Excel .csv file, go to File, Save As..., and change the file type from 'CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)' to a 'CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)' file type.
Drop the mic - fixed easily.