# R's read.csv prepending 1st column name with junk text

Tags: r, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have exported data from a result grid in SQL Server Management Studio to a csv file.
The csv file looks correct.

But when I read the data into an R dataframe using read.csv, the first column name is prepended with "**ï..**". How do I get rid of this junk text?

Example:

```
str(trainData)

'data.frame':   64169 obs. of  20 variables:    
 $ ï..Column1             : int  3232...   
 $ Column2                : int  4242...
```

The data looks something like this (nothing special) :

Column1,Column2
100116577,100116577
100116698,100116702

Comment: the `..` usually come from spaces being replaced by `.`'s. Is the `i` a part of the csv? I have only ever seen `X` being added to colnames when they start with a number.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the input data and the read.table command you used to read it?

Comment: You can also just replace it afterwords using regex. `names(trainData)[1] <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(trainData)[1])`

Comment: I just had this error and solved it by copying the dataset into a new .csv file - There were no spaces before the column names and I could not find another way to get rid of this symbol

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You've got a Unicode UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

> A text editor or web browser interpreting the text as ISO-8859-1 or
> CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this

R is giving you the ï and then converting the other two into dots as they are non-alphanumeric characters.

Here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-February/370760.html

Duncan Murdoch suggests:

> You can declare a file to be in encoding "UTF-8-BOM" if you want to
> ignore a BOM on input

So try your `read.csv` with `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` or persuade your SQL wotsit to not output a BOM.

Otherwise you may as well test if the first name starts with `ï..` and strip it with `substr` (as long as you know you'll never have a column that does start like that genuinely...)

Comment: Tried read.csv("data.csv",encoding="UTF-8-BOM") but still getting the BOM. When saving results to file from sql server man studio, the default encoding is UTF-8. Changed the encoding to ANSII and it removed the BOM.

Comment: If I create a file with a BOM I can't replicate your behaviour, so maybe its an operating system or a windows version thing. Using ANSI (or ASCII?) encoding will just make problems if you have any non-plain-english characters in your output... Could you post a sample file?

Comment: Important edit: the correct arg is `fileEncoding=` not `encoding=`, which is silently ignored by `read.csv`.