# ï»¿ or ? character is prepended to first column when reading csv file from s3 by using camel

Tags: csv, apache-camel

The csv file is located in S3 bucket, and I am using camel aws to consume the csv file. 
However, whenever the csv file is loaded to local, ï»¿  or ? character is pretended to first column.

For example, 
original file
firstname, lastname
brian,xi

after load to local
ï»¿firstname,lastname
brian,xi

I have done research on this link : [R's read.csv prepending 1st column name with junk text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text)
however, it does not seem to work for camel.

how to read csv file from s3
use aws-s3 to consume csv file from s3 bucket such as "Exchange s3File = consumer.receive(s3Endpoint)" where s3Endpoint = "aws-s3://keys&secret?prefix=%s&deleteAfterRead=false&amazonS3Client=#awsS3client"

Comment: Have you seen https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Handling_Byte_Order_Marks

Comment: Yes, I tried it. ' ï»¿' is converted to '?'. However, i found a work around. open .csv file with notepad++-> go to encoding and save as utf-8.   ' ï»¿' character is removed when i read csv file again.  However, this is not my preferred solution

Comment: You might provide more detail on what you tried, because BOMInputStream's purpose is to pull off the byte order mark characters.

Answer (score 1):

The characters `ï»¿` are a [**UTF-8 BOM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) (Hex EF BB BF). So this is meta data about the file content that is placed at the beginning of the file (because there is no "header" or similar place where it can be saved to).

If you **read a file that begins with this sequence**, but you **read it as Windows standard encoding** (CP1252) or ISO-8859-1, you get exactly these three strange characters at the beginning of the file content.

To avoid that you have to **read the file as UTF-8 and BOM aware** as suggested in @jws comment. He also provided [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Handling_Byte_Order_Marks) with an example how to use a `BOMInputStream` to read such files correctly.

If the file is correctly read, and you write it back into a file with a different encoding like CP1252, the BOM should be removed.

So, now the question is **how exactly do you read the file with Camel**? If you (or a library) read it (perhaps by default) with a non-UTF-8 encoding, that explains why you get these characters in the file content.

Comment: thanks for feedback. i updated my post, and under "how to read csv file" describes how i used camel to get csv file

Comment: There should be a message header `CamelAwsS3ContentEncoding` set by the S3 consumer. Have you checked this?