# R function read.csv inserts ï.. in first header name

Tags: r, csv, header, rstudio, read.csv

I have a csv file with a header containing two columns with names: DT.Business.Day and Store.Nr.

When I apply the function:

```
supply <- read.csv(file="C:/A...supply.csv",header=T,sep=",")
```

The first header name is transferred to ï..DT.Business.Day.

By what is this caused and what can I do to remain original header names?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text) solve your problem?