# R lapply function across a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, gsub

There are similar solutions to this question on the forum; however I cant get the code to work and need to ask a new question.

I have about 20 really wide csv files that I imported into the global environment. I need to be able to remove special characters and change the names of the columns that I pull from a CSV.

Here is example code of two data frames and then producing a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame("ï.ID" = 1, "Q.1" = 2, Q1.1 = 3)
df2 <- data.frame("ï.ID." = 2, "Q.1a" = 3, Q1.1 = 4)
Qs  <- data.frame("Original.Question" = "Q1a", "Question" = "Q.1")

dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))
```

When I import the files there is a BOM Character i with two dots over it in front of the ID column. I use the following code in individual data frames as my attempts to use lappy over the dflist have all failed.

```
names(df1) <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(df1))
```

The second thing I want to do is rename columns from a csv. Again I dont seem to have the correct function for this to work. The specific code I want to modify to loop across all data frames is:

```
names(df1)[names(df1) 
          %in% Qs$Original.Question] = Qs$Question[match(names(df1)[names(df1) 
          %in% Qs$Original.Question], Qs$Original.Question)]
```

This allows me to use a CSV to rename all of the question columns as they must be renamed prior to merging the data frames to a single data frame. Again I cant seem to be able to properly apply the lapply function.

My apologies for needing to ask a similar question again. I have tried to adapt code but have failed miserably.

Comment: Especially when the frames are of very similar structure and/or intent, it's often better to store them in a `list` originally instead of storing them in separate frames. The only time keeping them separate is when applying a function to just one of them (selectively) is the norm, and applying a function to all of them is the extreme exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to filter out `NULL` objects. You could do:

```
dflist <- Filter(Negate(is.null), dflist)
lapply(dflist, function(x) setNames(x,gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(x))))
[[1]]
   sex  school daysmissed
1    M   north          5
2    F   north          1
3    M central          2
4    M   south          0
5    F   south          7
6    F   south          1
7    F central          3
8    M   north          2
9    M   north          4
10   F   south         15

[[2]]
  ID Q1 Q11
1  1  2   3

[[3]]
  ID Q1a Q11
1  2   3   4

[[4]]
  OriginalQuestion Question
1              Q1a      Q.1
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu both code works. Is there anyway to apply it to the data frames in the global environment? Or can I rename the questions in the list of data frames and then merge them into one?

Comment: @Keelin you should look into `eapply` instead of `lapply` or simply use `list2env`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dataframe based on the pattern in their name. As in the example you have `df1`, `df2`, you can get all the dataframes in a list using the pattern as `'df'` followed by a number. Use `mget` to get them in a list, `lapply` over them and rename columns.

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df\\d+'))
dflist <- lapply(list_df, function(x) 
                 {names(x) <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(x));x})
```

Also you might be interested in [R's read.csv prepending 1st column name with junk text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text) which avoids getting the BOM character in first column.

Comment: All my files are different names based on a concatenation of year and time period so I cant pull based on name. Got an error with this: `> df1 <- data.frame("ï.ID" = 1, "Q.1" = 2, Q1.1 = 3)
> df2 <- data.frame("ï.ID." = 2, "Q.1a" = 3, Q1.1 = 4)
> Qs  <- data.frame("Original.Question" = "Q1a", "Question" = "Q.1")
> 
> dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))
> 
> dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) 
+ {names(x) <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(x));x})
Error in names(x) <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", names(x)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL`

Comment: In my answer I am not using `dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))`

Comment: I know yes although the real files are not named with df, all files are named with a concatenation of year, time period and type. There isnt a pattern across all of them.

Comment: so what are they named then? Anyway, you can use `dflist <- Filter(length, dflist)` after using `dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))` to remove `NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks for this @Ronak it works. I cant seem to tag both you and Onyambu in the same comment. But should I just apply the change in the list or in all df in the global environment? And then I need to apply the lapply function over the questions. Thanks ever so much for your time.

Comment: well, `dflist` would have list of dataframes with changed names, you can keep it as it is or if you want them as separate dataframes again do `list2env(dflist, .GlobalEnv)`